# Replacing Windows CRLF with Unix LF using Perl -- `Unrecognized switch: -g`?

Tags: perl, sh

## Problem Background

We have several thousand large (10M<lines) text files of tabular data produced by a windows machine which we need to prepare for upload to a database.

We need to change the file encoding of these files from `cp1252` to `utf-8`, replace any bare Unix LF sequences (i.e. `\n`) with spaces, then replace the DOS line end sequences ("CR-LF", i.e `\r\n`) with Unix line end sequences (i.e. `\n`).

The `dos2unix` utility is not available for this task.

We initially had a bash function that packaged these operations together using `iconv` and `sed`, with `iconv` doing the encoding and `sed` dealing with the LF/CRLF sequences. I'm trying to replace part of this bash function with a `perl` command.

## Example Code

[Based on some helpful code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/281801/222737), I want to change this function to a `perl` script.

The author of the code review suggested the following `perl` to replace CRLF (i.e. "`\r\n`") with LF ("`\n`").

```bash
perl -g -pe 's/(?<!\r)\n/ /g; s/\r\n/\n/g;'
```

The explanation for why this is better than what we had previously makes perfect sense, but this line fails for me with:

```bash
Unrecognized switch: -g  (-h will show valid options).
```

More interestingly, the author of the code review also suggests it is possible to perform the decode/recode in a perl script, too, but I am completely unsure where to start.

## Questions

Please can someone explain why the suggested answer fails with `Unrecognized switch: -g  (-h will show valid options).`?

If it helps, the line is supposed to receive piped input from `incov` as follows (though I am interested in learning how to use `perl` to do the redcoding/recoding step, too):

```bash
iconv --from-code=CP1252 --to-code=UTF-8 $1$ | \
perl -g -pe 's/(?<!\r)\n/ /g; s/\r\n/\n/g;' 
> "$2"
```

#### (Highly simplified) example input for testing:

```
apple|orange|\n|lemon\r\nrasperry|strawberry|mango|\n\r\n
```

#### Desired output:

```
apple|orange| |lemon\nrasperry|strawberry|mango| \n
```

Comment: `perl -g -pe 's/(?<!\r)\n/ /g; s/\r\n/\n/g;'` does not produce an error with v5.36.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl [recently added](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.36.0/perldelta) the command line switch `-g` as an alias for 'gulp mode' in Perl v5.36.0.

This works in Perl version v5.36.0:

```
s=$(printf "Line 1\nStill Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\r\n")
perl -g -pe 's/(?<!\r)\n/ /g; s/\r\n/\n/g;' <<<"$s"
```

Prints:

```
Line 1 Still Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

But any version of perl earlier than v5.36.0, you would do:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(?<!\r)\n/ /g; s/\r\n/\n/g;' <<<"$s"
# same
```

---

BTW, the conversion you are looking for a *way easier* in this case with `awk` since it is close to the defaults.

Just do this:

```
awk -v RS="\r\n" '{gsub(/\n/," ")} 1' <<<"$s"
Line 1 Still Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Or, if you have a file:

```
awk -v RS="\r\n" '{gsub(/\n/," ")} 1' file
```

This is superior to the posted `perl` solution since the file is processed record be record (each block of text separated by `\r\n`) versus having the read the entire file into memory.

(On Windows you *may* need to do `awk -v RS="\r\n" -v ORS="\n" '...'`)

Another note:

You can get similar behavior from Perl by:

1. Setting the input record separator to the fixed string `$/="\r\n"` in a `BEGIN` block;
2. Use the `-l` switch so every line has the input record separator removed;
3. Use `tr` for speedy replacement of `\n` with `' '`;
4. Possible set the output record separator, `$/="\n"`, on Windows.

Full command:

```
perl -lpE 'BEGIN{$/="\r\n"} tr/\n/ /' file
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is about the command line switch `-g` you use in `perl -g -pe ...`. This is not about the switch at the regex  - which is valid (but useless since there is only a single `\n` in a line anyway, and `-p` reads line by line).

This switch simply does not exist with the perl version you are using. It was only [added with perl 5.36](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.36.0/perldelta#-g-command-line-flag), so you are likely using an older version. Try `-0777` instead.

Comment: Isn't `-g` short for [gulp](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-g)? An alias of `-0777`

Comment: @dawg: you are right. This switch exists with the latest perl version but not the one used by the OP. Fixed the answer

Comment: I should have posted the perl version with the question! Lesson learnt for me there.